# Java script moment date caluculaton for Current date & current date+2 days

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Upon submission of the Form in React JS, in back end Node JS, I have requirements to capture the current date in the format of "Nov 26, 2020" and future date calculated based on the current date + 2 days (i.e Nov 28, 2020).

Using the JavaScript moment  I'm getting the current date
`currentDate=moment(new Date(Date.now())).format("MMMM D, YYYY")`,

Future date: `currentDate.moment().add(2).format("MMMM D, YYYY")`,

Please let me if any better approach on moment with refined code for using in node js.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify getting the current date as a string by just doing:

```
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY");
```

For the second question regarding adding two days, I would use the following in order to clarifiy what you are adding:

```
moment().add({days:2}).format("MMMM D, YYYY");
```

So, by combining those two you can do:

```
const now = moment();
const nowAsFormattedStr = now.format("MMMM D, YYYY");
// note: use .clone() if you don't want "now" to be altered by adding two days
const inTwoDaysAsFormattedStr = now.clone().add({days:2}).format("MMMM D, YYYY");
```